# Get the #! (Crunchbang)'s version of Openbox?

Tags: debian, openbox, crunchbang

I am planning to install Debian 8 on my next computer, and am preparing everything beforehand.
On my previous try to have a full on linux PC (and not a linux VM massively used), I discovered #!, and loved the aestetic. Now, I know #! is dead, and a quick look at it successors show they didn't got far.

Luckily, #! is, in fact, just a Debian with a custom OpenBox set as the windows manager, and projects like ArchBang make me hope that custom OpenBox is still alive somewhere.

So my question is, starting with a Debian 8 Server fresh install, how would I go about getting the look and feel of CrunchBang?

(Presumably, it would be setting up the desktop environment and getting the custom Openbox from... somewhere and installing them)

From what I can gather, #! use nitrogen, tint2 and conky on Openbox, the main question become, what is that "custom Openbox" that is cited on different sources as the "main difference between Debian and #!"

Comment: It only depends on the theme and icon set. plus backgrounds. you can easily copy them under your $HOME.

Comment: @IporSircer So the "custom Openbox" is merely a theme for standard Openbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am/was a moderator at the old CrunchBang forums)

> I know #! is dead, and a quick look at it successors show they didn't got far.

I help out over at https://www.bunsenlabs.org/ and we have a current release with the next under active development.

> what is that "custom Openbox" that is cited on different sources as the "main difference between Debian and #!"

The "custom Openbox" would refer to the various customisations and tweaks that were applied to the #! desktop over and above what might be found in a plain Debian openbox+tint2+compton+thunar, *et al.* installation.

These include, but are not limited to, the Crunchbang themes, the Openbox menu (and especially the pipemenus, which are not easily replicated) and several low-level configuration files, such as the polkit rules that allowed mounting of internal drives in thunar as a normal user.

The Crunchbang (Waldorf) repositories also contained a limited selection of custom-compiled packages that were not available in Debian wheezy at the time of release, such as *pnmixer*, used to provide the systray volume icon.

You are welcome to use our BunsenLabs repositories with your jessie system, they should be compatible:

https://www.bunsenlabs.org/repositories.html

Pro tip: `apt install bunsen-meta-all` should install the entire working desktop ;)

We also have a GitHub page but I can only post two links with this reputation :D

Comment: I found BunsenLabs yesterday, and was really pleased with it, your answer come just in time for me to not self answer :)